# Page from a website won't print to PDF in some browsers

Tags: safari, pdf, printing, firefox

I’m using Safari on macOS Catalina (version 10.15.7) to plan bus trips on octranspo.com. When I have the times and route finalized I’ll print the map to a PDF. If I use Firefox or Brave the page has a header and footer but is otherwise blank. Pages from other sites will print okay. I don’t have any special plug-ins installed in Safari to enable printing to PDF. Even with PDF plug-ins installed in Brave and Firefox, pages won’t print. Not a big problem but I was wondering if anybody has any ideas as to why this happens.

Brave - Version 1.60.118 Chromium: 119.0.6045.163 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Firefox - 119.0.1 (64-bit)

Safari - Version 15.6.1 (15613.3.9.1.16, 15613)

Cheers and thanks.

Comment: I just tried it in Safari and it works

Comment: Yes, Safari works just fine. It's the other browsers that have the problem.

Comment: Could you give me a example of the route

Comment: https://plan.octranspo.com/plan/TravelPlans?Accessible=false&AllowBike=false&AllowBus=true&AllowCar=false&AllowExpress=true&AllowEvent=true&AllowFlexi=false&AllowMetro=true&AllowNight=true&AllowRegular=true&AllowSchool=true&AllowTrain=true&AllowTramway=true&BikeOnBoard=false&Date=2023-11-25&DestinationIdentifier=T+BAYS&DestinationType=Landmark&DisplayPreferenceOnly=false&OriginIdentifier=ChIJ-flX_0vjzUwRaXJvS3wVuxo&OriginType=ExternalLocation&PreferredRoutes=75%2C57&ShowOptions=false&Time=14%3A0&TimeType=SpecifiedDepartureTime&UseDefaultSites=false

Answer (score 1):

For me it prints in Safari and Google Chrome

Here is the print preview in Chrome

[image: preview]

In Chrome you have to use the Print Icon shown here

[image: icon]

Comment: Thanks for looking. I don't use Chrome. Safari works just dandy. I'm just curious why it doesn't work in Brave and Firefox. I'm not going to spend anymore time on it. Thanks again.